# Django auto generated form-fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

What I want to do is some of the fields in my form to be automatically added according to the previous value. Let me show you my example:

***my model***

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subgroup = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    number=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    voltage= models.PositiveIntegerField()
    comment = models.TextField(default='no comment')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group
```

***forms.py***

```
class MeasurementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Measurement
        fields = ['group','subgroup','number','voltage','comment']
```

***my views.py***

```
def measurement(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MeasurementForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            measurement = form.save(commit=False)
            measurement.save()
            return redirect('data:measurement')
    else:
        form = MeasurementForm()
    context = {'form': form,}
    template = 'data/measurement.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

***html.file***

```
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Add a measurement</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <button type = 'submit' class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What I would like to have though is the fields `group`, `subgroup` and `number` to be automatically generated according to what I entered before. 
For example, first measurement I enter:

Group:`House` Subgroup:`Light` Number:`1`  Voltage: `10` Comment: `No comment`

Once I click save I want the fields `Group`, `Subgroup` and `Number` to have the following information already:

Group:`House` Subgroup:`Light` Number:`2`  Voltage: `12` Comment: `No comment`

The next one:

Group:`House` Subgroup:`Light` Number:`3`  Voltage: `15` Comment: `No comment`

In order to add only my measurement and save time. However that does not mean that I can't change the  `Group`, `Subgroup` or `Number` fields.

Comment: use jquery to make an ajax call (not to refresh the page and lose values) and dynamically set the desired fields, in your case - 'number'.

Eg - 
`
    $.ajax({
         type : "POST"
         url : "form_action_url",
         data : "form_data",
         success : function (data) {
                $('#number_field_id').value += 1;
         }
    })
`